# Can't see what I'm typing in iterm2

Tags: rspec, command-line-interface, iterm, iterm2

Periodically, I'll run rspec (though I don't know if its specific to that) and suddenly, I can't see what i'm typing.  I have to close that iterm2 window out and open a new one.  Then that will work fine for a while and iterm2 will hide my typing again.  I can always see responses to my commands, just not my typing or cursor.  It also does this weird stacking thing where it pushes each new line farther to the right.

[image]

Update!:

I tried the suggestion to type in stty echo and can see my text, but the weird indention remains:

[image]

Comment: try typing in stty echo a few times

Comment: I'll try that next time it happens and let you know.  thanks!

Comment: I can see my text after doing that, but the weird indention remains...

Comment: Same problem... Echo also doesn't help...

Answer (score 46):

Typing "stty sane" Fixes this for me.

Comment: Fixed it for me too, but what does this even do?

Comment: or what is causing this?  Did I bump some key on the keyboard that makes this happen ?

Comment: I have got the same problem and it seems I have to execute "stty sane" all the time: how to persist it?

Answer (score 13):

Clean up this and many other issues with `stty sane`.

Got this from a bit of Googling:

> same as `cread -ignbrk brkint -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iutf8 -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke`, all special characters to their default values.

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/stty.htm