# Running "rspec" in Mac Terminal with Ruby makes my text invisible. How do I stop this from happening in the first place?

Tags: ruby, macos, rspec, terminal

I'm having problems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073559/cant-see-what-im-typing-in-iterm2), so I know how to make the text reappear *after* it disappears: just type "stty echo" or "reset." But how do I prevent it from happening in the first place? Why does it happen?

**Update 10/24/15:** I figured out the issue. Whenever I was using binding.pry and exited it with CTRL-C, the problem occurred. Now I exit binding.pry the "legal" way, by typing "exit!", and I haven't had invisible text since then.

Comment: I don't know what rspec is, but if it's a command that is just supposed to output text, you could could try running `rspec | cat` or `rspec | cat -v` so that the stdout of rspec isn't a tty. Just something to try.

Comment: Hi - rspec is a code-testing gem: http://rspec.info/

Comment: Are you by any change using `guard`?

Comment: No, not using `guard`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at your configuration file first in your User Home Directory path `~/.rspec` or see in root of your project if you have a file called `.rspec` if you're using mac that these files are actually hidden. Rspec version 3 there is another file called `.rspec-local` in root of your application. You should view or edit any files and see what configurations they have:

Try changing these configurations:

`--no-color` to `--color`

The rest are as follows which I don't think you should change them:

```
--format progress
--no-profile
--no-fail-fast
--order defined
```

You can change them to:

```
--format documentation
--profile
--fail-fast
--order random
```

If you do not have any of these files you might want to create a file in your user directory and open it with a text editor and add `--color` to it.

Comment: Thanks - that doesn't seem to be the issue, as the configuration is set to `--color` already.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?